# why hibernate is trying to get classes by proxy names to load classes from jar?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to use latest hibernate 5.3.6 Final with WildFly 14 in my application, hibernate fails to load the classes mapped to entity with relations. In logs it seems that it is trying to load the associated classes with their proxy names in .Jar file.

```
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 15:14:38.288 [default task-1] ERROR com.tlbo.bo.BaseBusinessMethods - com.tlbo.bo.personinfo.impl.client.PersonImpl$HibernateProxy$cCWcZAbjImplM from [Module "deployment.ctools.ear.ctservices.jar" from Service Module Loader]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tlbo.bo.personinfo.impl.client.PersonImpl$HibernateProxy$cCWcZAbjImplM from [Module "deployment.ctools.ear.ctservices.jar" from Service Module Loader]
```

Error in wildFly logs:

```
2018-09-24 15:14:38,198 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl] (default task-1) Starting ResultSet row #0
2018-09-24 15:14:38,198 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl] (default task-1) On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
2018-09-24 15:14:38,227 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (default task-1) Resolving associations for [com.tlbo.bo.artifact.impl.FileAttachmentImpl#190aa8c077d8fa3b161f9cbf51677ce]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 15:14:38.288 [default task-1] ERROR com.tlbo.bo.BaseBusinessMethods - com.tlbo.bo.personinfo.impl.client.PersonImpl$HibernateProxy$cCWcZAbjImplM from [Module "deployment.ctools.ear.ctservices.jar" from Service Module Loader]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tlbo.bo.personinfo.impl.client.PersonImpl$HibernateProxy$cCWcZAbjImplM from [Module "deployment.ctools.ear.ctservices.jar" from Service Module Loader]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255) ~[?:?]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410) ~[?:?]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) ~[?:?]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116) ~[?:?]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at com.tlbo.bo.BaseBusinessMethods.addMethodToMap(BaseBusinessMethods.java:152) [ctservices.jar:?]
2018-09-24 15:14:38,308 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at com.tlbo.bo.BaseBusinessMethods.getMethods(BaseBusinessMethods.java:106) [ctservices.jar:?]
```

I searched for such scenarios, but didn't found anything about it. Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance!